# How to display Bing results only in a certain language?

Tags: localization, bing

Is there something similar to [Google Advanced Search](http://www.google.com/advanced_search%00), where you can set the preferred language for the search results, for Bing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, go to the "Settings" page and choose the "Web" tab, it's setting that you need. The direct link is http://www.bing.com/account/web?ru=%2f&meru=%252f

[image]